# R Shiny keycode of user input

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, keycode

I have to get the keycode in a textInput. For this purpose, i developed this code bellow:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

tags$script(sprintf('$(document).on("shiny:sessioninitialized", function(event) { // wait for shiny to be loaded
document.getElementById("%s").onkeydown = function(event) {
    Shiny.onInputChange("%s", [event.keyCode,event.timeStamp]);
};
});',"textInput","jsrow")),

HTML(sprintf("<div 'form-group shiny-input-container'>
                             <label for='%s'>%s</label>
                             <input class='form-control' charset='UTF-8' type='text' placeholder='%s' onkeydown = 'return (event.keyCode >=48 && event.keyCode <= 57)
                             || event.keyCode == 8||(event.keyCode >=37 && event.keyCode <= 40)||(event.keyCode >=33 && event.keyCode <= 34)||event.keyCode == 46
                             ||event.keyCode == 45||event.keyCode == 9||event.keyCode == 13||event.keyCode == 32||(event.keyCode >=16 && event.keyCode <= 18)||event.keyCode == 189
                             ||event.keyCode == 173||(event.keyCode >=112 && event.keyCode <= 123)||event.keyCode == 144||(event.keyCode >=96 && event.keyCode <= 105)' id='%s' required>
                             </div>", "textInput", "", "41741-155", "textInput")
)

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

observeEvent(input$jsrow, {
    print(paste0("Value of input is ", input$jsrow[1]))
})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But when I modularize the textInput, the code no longer works. Any idea?

Comment: I'm not a star in JavaScript but why do you define two `onkeydown` event handlers ? What is the `onkeydown` event handler you attach in `HTML(......)` supposed to do ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, the onkeydown event handler on HTML blocks the keyboard for some keys. For example, a numerical input is not allowed in a text field as well as some special characters: ? . + - , et cetera.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. Can't you group the two event handlers in a single one ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
library(shiny)

textInput2 <- function(inputId, label, value = "", width = NULL, 
                       placeholder = NULL, onkeydown = NULL){
  input <- textInput(inputId, label, value, width, placeholder)
  input$children[[2]] <- 
    htmltools::tagAppendAttributes(input$children[[2]], onkeydown = "%s")
  tag <- as.character(input)
  HTML(sprintf(tag, onkeydown))
}

js <- "Shiny.setInputValue('jsrow', [event.keyCode,event.timeStamp]); 
       return !((event.which >=48 && event.which <= 57)
          || event.which == 8||(event.which >=37 && event.which <= 40)||(event.which >=33 && event.which <= 34)||event.which == 46
          ||event.which == 45||event.which == 9||event.which == 13||event.which == 32||(event.which >=16 && event.which <= 18)||event.which == 189
          ||event.which == 173||(event.which >=112 && event.which <= 123)||event.which == 144||(event.which >=96 && event.which <= 105))
          ;
       "

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput2("textinput", "Enter text:", onkeydown = js)
)

server <- function(input, output){
  observeEvent(input$jsrow, {
    print(paste0("Value of input is ", input$jsrow[1]))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And in a module, just use `ns` as usual.

---

## EDIT

```
js <- function(id) {sprintf("Shiny.setInputValue('%s_jsrow', [event.keyCode,event.timeStamp]); 
       return !((event.which >=48 && event.which <= 57)
       || event.which == 8||(event.which >=37 && event.which <= 40)||(event.which >=33 && event.which <= 34)||event.which == 46
       ||event.which == 45||event.which == 9||event.which == 13||event.which == 32||(event.which >=16 && event.which <= 18)||event.which == 189
       ||event.which == 173||(event.which >=112 && event.which <= 123)||event.which == 144||(event.which >=96 && event.which <= 105));", id)}


ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput2("textinput", "Enter text:", onkeydown = js("textinput"))
)

server <- function(input, output){
  observeEvent(input$textinput_jsrow, {
    print(paste0("Value of input is ", input$textinput_jsrow[1]))
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @StéphaneLaurent for the quickly response! But actually what I need is to get the keycode by each textInput element. Note that in the code that you posted above, the input$jsrow variable is modified by any textInput in the fluidPage. Thats exacly what I want avoid using document.getElementById("%s").

Comment: @ StéphaneLaurent, thank you so much for your help, and that's exacly what I was looking forward. But, istead of use the native textInput tag what I need is to use something like the HTML code posted in my question for create the input form (HTML(sprintf("<input>...</input>")), you know how to do that)?

Comment: Thank you so much @StéphaneLaurent, but I adapted your code and managed to modularize it. However, when I press a number, exit the module and come back it is as if the number had been pressed again. Do you know how to improve this point? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @HarrisonHenri I don't understand what you mean by "exit the module and come back". Maybe post a new question with your code.

Comment: I modularized the code that you wrote, so @StéphaneLaurent, I'm looking for a way to reset the variable text input js row to null every time I call the module.

Comment: @HarrisonHenri I don't see what you mean. Please open a new question, or edit this one and include your modularized code.

Comment: Here's the link @StéphaneLaurent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116685/reset-input-when-call-the-module-in-shiny.